# MVC 3 - Form Validation with annotations

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The "remote" annotation in MVC 3 allows you to call an “action” to do property data validation for you. It’s beautiful! Or… is it really?

Problem: The "remote" annotation below (see comment) calls code in the client!! And my Role class is in the model. I liked "remote" because I don't need to write custom validators.

Should I use the Object View Model pattern and have the property “Role.Name” duplicated in there? That’d work. Then another problem: how do I really avoid the DRY principle (Don’t Repeat Yourself)? Is it efficient to have a property with annotations in the Object View, then the same property in the Model? I mean, is this too much work for separation of concerns?

I'm just trying to design this right and apply right design principles so I don't get burned when this website grows code-wise.

What's the best way to do this?

```
namespace StartWeb.Model.ObjectModel
{
 public class Role  //this class is in the Model (see namespace) and it needs to be "client agnostic”
    {

         //Then, this annotation is NOT client agnostic, it calls a controller:
        [Remote("ValidateRoleName", "Role", AdditionalFields="InitialRoleName", ErrorMessage = "Role Name already exists")]
        public  string Name { get; set; }
```

This is the validation code in the RoleController action (in the "client"):

```
    [HttpGet]
    [OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public JsonResult ValidateRoleName(string name, string initialRoleName)
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        if (name != initialRoleName) isValid = !(new SecurityFacade().IsRoleNameExist(name));           
        return Json(isValid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional research, I found this open source tool that can do the heavy-lifting for you mapping entities from different layers:

[Automapper tool between domain model and view models](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/)